# Find the nth element in a tuple using the function below

Tags: haskell, tuples

"Use the below function with two parameters:

```
nth :: (a,a,a,a,a) -> Int -> a
```

where the Int value should return the Int-th value of the five-element tuple."
I tried:

```
nth (a,b,c,d,e) x = (a,b,c,d,e) !! x
```

But GHC gave me an error message:

```
file.hs:11:21: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[a1]'
              with actual type `(a, b, c, d, e)'
* In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `(a, b, c, d, e)'
  In the expression: (a, b, c, d, e) !! x
  In an equation for `nth':
      nth (a, b, c, d, e) x = (a, b, c, d, e) !! x
* Relevant bindings include
    e :: e (bound at file.hs:11:14)
    d :: d (bound at file.hs:11:12)
    c :: c (bound at file.hs:11:10)
    b :: b (bound at file.hs:11:8)
    a :: a (bound at file.hs:11:6)
    nth :: (a, b, c, d, e) -> Int -> a1
      (bound at file.hs:11:1)
```

What should I do? How should I write the tuple part of this equation?
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: there's actually an easy fix, you'll just have to change two symbols: `nth (a,b,c,d,e) x = [a,b,c,d,e] !! x`. It might not be an efficient implementation but I'll argue n-tuples are not really supposed to be a homogeneous container type, nor efficient random access with `Int` anyway. Plus it's easy to type :)

Comment: @Javran of course it's not homogeneous so the list trick just won't work at all -- you can't put different type values in one list.

Comment: @WillNess which part of it doesn't work? The question wants something of type `nth :: (a,a,a,a,a) -> Int -> a` and I see no correctness issue.

Comment: @Javran you're right, I wasn't paying attention to this part and assumed a more general type. which wouldn't make any sense either, since we must return _one_ type. d'oh! (I blame sleep deprivation ;) ) ----- your answer is missing. :)

Comment: @WillNess I originally just wanted to leave it as a comment as I myself considered that to be just a trick rather than "the proper way", but yeah I think I can convert it to an answer to elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use [**`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) since, as the signature says, it works on lists, not tuples. You can work with pattern matching and implement this as:

```
nth :: (a, a, a, a, a) -> Int -> a
nth (a, _, _, _, _) 0 = a
nth (_, b, _, _, _) 1 = b
nth (_, _, c, _, _) 2 = c
nth (_, _, _, d, _) 3 = d
nth (_, _, _, _, e) 4 = e
```

There have been proposals where a 3-tuple is defined as `(a, (b, c))` such that it is thus a recursive structure where an *n*-tuple is defined as a *2*-tuple with an *n-1*-tuple as second item. But this is not the case (at the moment).

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid some of the repetition from the existing pattern-matching solutions by separating the pattern match for the tuple from the match on `n`:

```
nth :: (a, a, a, a, a) -> Int -> a
nth (a, b, c, d, e) n = case n of
  0 -> a
  1 -> b
  2 -> c
  3 -> d
  4 -> e
```

You should also consider what you want to happen when n is not in the range `[0, 4]`. As written, you will get a non-exhaustive pattern error at runtime. It would be more honest to either return a `Maybe a` or take a more constrained type as input, like

```
data QuintupleIndex = Zero | One | Two | Three | Four
```

Comment: I guess the `go` is there to avoid repeating `nth (a, b, c, d, e)` lots of times? If so, you could `nth (a, b, c, d, e) n = case n of ...`. If you must have the "memoization" behavior there's LambdaCase: `nth (a, b, c, d, e) = \case ...`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, just to avoid repeating the tuple five times. Using `case` is a good suggestion - I guess I was being pointlessly point-free. I don't really like to suggest language extensions to newcomers. I'm curious what memoization behavior you're referring to: what different operational semantics does the LambdaCase solution have from case/of?

Comment: For example, `map (nth (1,2,3,4,5))` will re-pattern-match once for each list element with `f x y = case y of` but only once with `f x = \case` (or `f x = \y -> case y of`).

Answer (score 3):

(converted from my own comments)

There's actually an easy fix that haven't been mentioned in other answers: you'll just have to change two symbols:

```hs
nth :: (a, a, a, a, a) -> Int -> a
nth (a,b,c,d,e) x = [a,b,c,d,e] !! x

-- or alternatively
nth (a,b,c,d,e) = ([a,b,c,d,e] !!)
```

There's still pattern matching to be done to find the n-th element, but it's now handled implicitly in `!!`.

This works because list is homogeneous, meaning all of its elements are of the same type. On the left hand side of `nth`, you have the pattern `(a,b,c,d,e)`, so type inference gives the most general constraint `a :: a, b :: b, ...` as indicated in the error message. However, once `[a,b,c,d,e]` is seen on the right hand side, it gives type inference a clue that all of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` are of the same type! So type inference can now determine that `(a,b,c,d,e) :: (a,a,a,a,a)` typechecks.

In Haskell, tuples are not meant to be container types that you index with `Int` like a list (unlike tuples in Python and some other languages), rather it's more of a structure that each field serves a specific meaning (think it as `struct` in C), if you do want efficient indexing into that, you'll need field selectors rather than natural numbers:

```hs
data Five a = Five { _1 :: a,  _2 :: a,  _3 :: a,  _4 :: a,  _5 :: a }
```

Now that you can access fields with `_x`, but the type of `nth` will be :

```hs
nth :: Five a -> (Five a -> a) -> a
nth v f = f v

-- or pointfreely:
nth = flip id
```

(another nice thing about this is that you have a complete function rather than one that might fail pattern matches and raise an exception)

Note that field selectors are functions rather than natural numbers - if you are dealing with list indices, it makes sense to ask "what is the next element?", but less so when it comes to a structure.

Answer (score 2):

The `(!!)` function only works on lists.

For tuples, at least those of more than 2 elements, the only way to access the elements is by direct pattern matching:

```
nth :: (a,a,a,a,a) -> Int -> a
nth (a, _, _, _, _) 0 = a
nth (_, a, _, _, _) 1 = a
nth (_, _, a, _, _) 2 = a
nth (_, _, _, a, _) 3 = a
nth (_, _, _, _, a) 4 = a
```

(note the `_`s, which mean "I don't care what this value" is. You could give them a name instead - eg match on `(a, b, c, d, e)` on each line and have the returned value being `a` on the first line, `b` on the second and so on. But it's less visual "noise" to only name the values you care about.)

Also note that this function will crash with a "non-exhaustive patterns" error if the integer argument is anything outside 0-4. But using `(!!)` on a list of 5 elements has a similar flaw. You can easily add a default case to the end, although that's not easy when working with a completely generic type `a` because there is no value that will work as a return value of any type the function might be called with!

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution using guards is as follows:

```hs
nth :: (a,a,a,a,a) -> Int -> a
nth (a, b, c, d, e) i
  | i == 0    = a
  | i == 1    = b
  | i == 2    = c
  | i == 3    = d
  | otherwise = e
```